# What does the ".bss" command do in MSP430 assembly code? For example what does ".bss beep_cnt,2" do with the variable beep_cnt2?

Tags: assembly, msp430

What does the ".bss" command do in MSP430 assembly code? For example what does ".bss    beep_cnt,2" do with the variable beep_cnt2?

```
.bss    beep_cnt,2              ; beeper flag
.bss    delay_cnt,2             ; delay flag
```

Comment: If it has anything in common with x86 .bss, it declares uninitialized memory.

Comment: I'm using the TI MSP430g2553. http://www.ti.com/product/msp430g2553. Not sure if it's the same as x86

Comment: Not the same as x86, just if it means the same thing as in x86.

Comment: what assembler are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The term BSS is universal in assembly and C programming, across operating system no less. Core concept stuff, originally an acronym for "Block Started by Symbol" with a tongue-in-cheek version of Better Save Space.  Goes back to the mid 1950s, started by an IBM 704 assembler and adopted into Fortran and flung from there.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) has the history.  Not otherwise mentioning the effort to get rid of globals over the past 20 years.

So it is reserving two bytes in the data segment that's zero-initialized at startup.